# Why can't I use app.MainLoop() with iPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, ipython

I'd like a rectangle to appear every time the user clicks on the line. I've gotten this to work procedurally like in this example: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216648 but once I implemented iPython compatibility and started using classes, I could no longer use the app.MainLoop() without the program crashing. How do I refresh a wx.Frame object from inside a class? Why does the self.figure.canvas.draw() not work?

The code is below. Open ipython with the -pylab option. x = [-10,10] and y = x are decent parameters for this problem.

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanv
from pylab import *
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()
import sys

class MainCanvas(wx.Frame):
    """ Set up the canvas and plot on which the rectangle will lie """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1, size=(550,350))
        self.x = args[0]
        self.y = args[1]

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.plot(*args)
        self.line, = self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y, picker = 3,
                visible = False) 
        self.canvas = FigCanv(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 2, 2, visible=True)
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onPick)

    def onPick(self, event):
        """ Move rectangle to last click on line """     
        self.rect.set_x(event.mouseevent.xdata)
        self.rect.set_y(event.mouseevent.ydata)
        self.rect.set_visible(True)
        print "rect x: ", self.rect.get_x()
        print "rect y: ", self.rect.get_y()          
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

def run_this_plot(self, arg_s=''):
    """ Run in iPython
    Examples
    In [1]: import demo
    In [2]: runplot x y <z> 
    Where x, y, and z are numbers of any type
    """
    args = []
    for arg in arg_s.split():
        try:
            args.append(self.shell.user_ns[arg])
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid argument: %r" % arg)
    mc = MainCanvas(*args)

ip.expose_magic("runplot", run_this_plot)
```

Thanks!
--Erin

Comment: I think that the real question which you should be asking is: "Why I cannot use app.MainLoop()?" or "How do I combine IPython with wxPython?" You really should not be using wx.Frame without mainloop in wx.

Comment: How do I use mainloop in this context? I'd appreciate any docs or other sources of information specific to this iPython/wxPython interaction that you could point me to.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know about iPython. But wxPython will not work properly without the main loop as far as I know. If both libraries use some sort of infinite loop to function properly it might not be trivial. Is not there any wx example in your iPython distribution? I think I have seen something along the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that matplotlib is set to use a backend other than wx.  Try either setting this in the matplotlibrc file, or it can be set in the program (but it must be set before matplotlib is imported). Instructions are [here](http://matplotlib.github.com/faq/installing_faq.html#what-is-a-backend).

Comment: I've set the backend in matplotlibrc to WXAgg and I've also tried just WX- unfortunately, neither had any effect :-/ I've tried this on two different setups- a Linux box and a Windows 7 machine. Does the above code run for you? If so, could you post your matplorlibrc? Thanks :)

Comment: The backend had to be set to WX and the line "self.figure.canvas.draw()" needed to be replaces with just "draw()." Thanks!